# How to insert into two temp tables in SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a project and I want to insert into two tables with the SQL query like this:

```sql
SELECT *
INTO #temp1, #temp2
FROM table
```

I actually want to insert the same items (rows) in two temp tables.

Is there any way to do this by a single query?

Comment: Do you have an actual requirement? Or are you just trying to keep your code DRY? (which isn't usually a goal with SQL, at least not the way it is in a regular programming language).

Comment: If you want to create two new temp tables and insert the rows into them the minimal number of statements is two `SELECT * INTO #temp1 FROM table; SELECT * INTO #temp2 FROM #temp1` - but what is the motivation for using `SELECT ... INTO` here? This will create a heap with no indexes which often isn't the ideal choice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, that tricky `OUTPUT` clause. Yes it can be done.

```
INSERT INTO #Temp1
OUTPUT INSERTED.Value INTO #Temp2
SELECT V.val 
FROM (
    VALUES ('A'), ('B'), ('C')
) V(val)
```

Note that with this form of the INSERT, both target tables need to be created in advance.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/y6X23dsr).

Comment: I'd have to resort to triggers, but that would be cheating.